# Enforce password for Ubuntu user on EC2 instances

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have an "**Amazon EC2 ubuntu**" instance and have the keyfile (somekeyfile.pem) to access the instance via SSH. I have shared the keyfile(somekeyfile.pem) file with a vendor as well to deploy the project stuff. But now I want to revoke the access from that vendor. For this I have tried following methods.

```
(1) Set root password using the command 
sudo passwd

(2) Set ubuntu password using the command 
sudo passwd ubuntu

(3) Modify the /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    and set PasswordAuthentication yes
    then restart the SSH service 

(4) Modified /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users and changed 

ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

to:

ubuntu ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Still vendor and i can login to the instance using the keypair only. is there any way to enable the password with keypair/.pem authentication. Please guide. I know Sudo command ask the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should not have shared your private key.

Private keys are **private**.

What you should have done instead is asking your user to create his own private/public key pair and communicate you the **public** one so that you could append it to the `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

To allow a key to connect to a host via SSH using a specific user, what you need to do is to append the corresponding **public** key to this user's `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

To revoke a key, all you need to do is remove the corresponding line of the `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` file for this user.

If you are not comfortable with the public/private key mechanisms you should read about it first.

To solve your problem:

1. Create a new private/public key pair. The private key will replace
   your current `somekeyfile.pem` and hold it private this time!
2. Append the public key to the corresponding `.ssh/authorized_keys`
3. Make sure you can log in with the new private key
4. Remove the line corresponding to the old key in the `.ssh/authorized_keys`

Warning: If you mess up you will end up not being able to reach your host anymore so make sure the new key works before you revoke the old one.